# How can I prevent Boost front page cache being cleared on logout?

Tags: 7, caching

Drupal 7, Boost 7.1.beta1, cache_expiration 7.1.alpha3 - Boost seems to work for the most part except that the boost cache is cleared too often for the front page (other pages too, but less frequently than the frontpage). Noticeably, whenever I log out from admin (and I'm redirected to the frontpage) the boost cache tag in the frontpage's page source is updated, meaning the frontpage expired and a new one regenerated. I don't have any exceptions in the boost configuration so all pages should cache and I have boost's maximum cache lifetime set for html to 4 weeks, everything else is set to 1 day. Drupal Core anonymous and block caching are off. Cron runs every three hours. I notice the frontpage gets re-cached about every hour (and of course on logout). As I mention other pages stay cached relatively longer but never respecting the 4 week max lifetime (usually a day or less). I don't see any updates/new content on front page (and def not on other pages) for expire to trigger. Possibly a nws weather widget triggering expire? I'm fairly new to drupal and boost. Thanks for any help, suggestions.